# PHP Cookies not showing?

Tags: php, cookies

I am attempting to create a PHP website handling logging in to a website.

My goal is to simply have a way that someone can log on through a service widget. The authorization goes through and one of the things with it is that I send it to another php page with the authorization details to check if the data returned from the login widget is legitimate. If it isn't, it will just error and redirect back to login. That part works well but the issue that arises which I don't understand because I am fairly new to PHP is the issue where the cookies do not update into the $_COOKIE array(dictionary?).

So it directs to another php file and handles that. If the authorization goes through it will create a cookie like this:

```
setcookie('user', $user_data, time()+3600, "/", $domain, true);
```

So then it redirects back to the login page with

```
header('Location: test_login.php')
```

Then when I check if it is set with the following

```
isset($_COOKIE['user'])
```

This returns FALSE?? and I checked the inspect and the cookie very much exists in the browser! I don't understand. I checked it and it shows what seem to be everything working. It seems like it would be able to access it. I am unsure why. Is there anything or any ideas that could be causing this issue?

Comment: `isset($_COOKIE['user'])` returns boolean on its own.

Comment: I understand. It always returns false on the next page. The cookie is set.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I wonder what Chrome developer tools shows for the request headers.

Comment: Check your log for `headers` already sent warnings when you try to set the cookie.

Comment: There are no errors. I am checking in Firefox. The cookies set just fine.

Comment: You need to use `if` against `isset()`.

Comment: I understand. That is also there.

Answer (score 0):

According to a comment reply, the if is missing from the code. Here's the fix:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']))
```

Alternatively, I would use something like this to check the existence of a cookie:

```
if($_COOKIE['user']!="")
```

Unset cookies will equal an empty string, while set cookies won't. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although cookies can be used for auth, they are something that the Client side can manipulate.. so fro mte browser I can set any cokie I want, and if your backend/server side relies on Cookie "user" to be "someuser", I can bruteforce this and set it to something which can be valid, thus takeover your user account..

I suggest you use `$_SESSION`s, which live only on the server side, and are not exposed to the frontend... similar to $_COOKIE, bur hidden from the frontend..

So, upon Authentication you can set $_SESSION['user'] = 'someusername', which I would not be able to reset from a frontend perspective..

You can start here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php